# Excel: Copy groups of data from the same column

Tags: excel, vba, macros, extract

I get an Excel sheet from an external party that looks likes this.
This is all one column and each [] is one row.

```
[Title]
 [Cat]
  [subtitle]
   [ID]
   [ID]
   [ID]
  [subtitle]
   [ID]
 [Cat]
  [subtitle]
   [ID]
[Title]
 [Cat]
  [subtitle]
   [ID]
```

I know this not an ideal format however this is the only format i get. Now i want to select the range of data from this column: title to title within title cat tot cat and within cat subtitle to subtitle. Is this possible and if this is possible how?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's probably possible but it's a bit unclear what you are asking. Do you want to select line 3 to 7 or do you want multiple ranges? Also, do the cells actually contain `[Title]` or is it a placeholder for the real title? If so, how do you know which is which? Either way, you need to get active yourself first and provide some code you tried. People don't like to do your work for you, they do like to help if you're stuck on a problem though.

Comment: Thanks for the comment,  I don't have a clue where to start. All the title, cat etc are placeholder and contain variable text. And my purpose is to group them by item, For example i want all the ID's from one subtitle and all the subtitles from one Cat. But I can't find a way to make this happen, and i seek help to get a direction which possible can help me. I dont need all the code just a direction ;).

Comment: To start, I would suggest checking out the `Range.Find` method or you could probably do it with thee loops (one for title to title, one for cat to cat, one for subtitle to subtitle). Edit: if they contain variable text, you obviously need to find a way to identify them first. Maybe the IDs all have a format that is easily distinguished from the other titles? If the cells contain the spaces like your example, you could use these

Answer (score 0):

This seems like an ideal situation for a Select Case based on the first characters of the cell:

```
For i = 1 To 15
    Select Case InStr(Cells(i, 1).Value, "[")
        Case 1
            'This is a Title
        Case 2
            'This is a Cat
        Case 3
            'This is a subtitle
        Case 4
            'This is an ID
    End Select
Next i
```